# Excel formula hide line break in Defined Name

Tags: excel

Is there a way to disable the display of line breaks mid-formula?

Note, for readability ¶ represents a line break/newline character below, though in the workbook it's an actual line break (i.e., made with `Chr(10)` or <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>).

I'm making a workbook for a customer with tables that in the header row have **Column Title ¶ (Units)** and Word Wrap enabled. When the table extends to having 13 columns, units like **operations/item**, and titles like **Total Cable Length ¶ (meters) ¶ *For feed time***, formulas using these mid-formula complete with line breaks get quite unwieldy.

Currently in the formula bar when I have my formula cell selected, it displays only `=Table1[[#Totals],[Surface Energy` and the rest is cut off, but ideally I'd like it to display `=Table1[[#Totals],[Surface Energy(dynes)]]+Table1[[#Totals],[Power(Watts)]]+Table1[[#Totals],[Heat Capacity(kJ/kg-K)]]`. I don't want to have to expand the formula bar halfway down the screen just because of all these line breaks.

I notice that if I turn off Word Wrap on the column headers, the ¶ characters are nicely collapsed into a single line. Can I do something similar to the display of formulas, or can someone recommend an alternate setup of my data to avoid this issue? Perhaps there is a character that displays as a line break when word-wrapped, but never otherwise?

[image: Formula shows line break mid-formula because of Defined Names]

Comment: If I understand you correctly, why can't you just remove or not add the line breaks?

Comment: You can of course use *alt+enter* in your formula too. But Excel wants absolutely to display the whole formula on the worksheet. So it will add extra EOL chars when displaying.

Comment: I don't think you can change this behavior, other than by removing the line break characters from the heading. One way around this is to hide the table header row and put text above it that acts as the table heading. But it kinda defeats the table functionality that way.

Comment: If this is purely for stylistic purposes, you can merge a bunch of cells to see the whole formula at once.

Comment: This is not to improve functionality, it is only to make formulas easier to understand and edit at a glance.

I can't remove/not add the line breaks because then the styling of the table itself would be destroyed, which is even worse than the formula being difficult to understand.

The best option I see so far is from jkpieterse, which would work, but as he said it kinda defeats table functionality and is probably also less desirable than just having difficult-to-view formulas.

Answer (score 0):

This can't be changed but here are two workarounds:

1. Use the CTRL+SHIFT+U keyboard shortcut to expand/collapse the formula window.  The expanded window size can be dragged to be as large as the screen.
2. Formulas can also be made easier to follow by inserting line breaks into them with ALT+ENTER. Excel evaluates the formulas as normal. The screen grab below shows a trivial example.

I think the suggestion in the comments to have a proxy header and hide the table header is the best alternative solution although that might cause problems, particularly if the spreadsheet is shared to and modified by others.

[image]

Comment: First, that Ctrl+Shift+U shortcut sounds handy, thank you. By default, it expands to the last-selected height, so I can toggle between filling half the screen and only one line. Second, adding a line break is done with Alt+Enter, not Ctrl+Enter.

Comment: No worries.  I've edited the answer to fix that error, thanks.     Another shortcut I use a lot is is Ctrl+F1 which shows/hides the ribbon.  Screen "real estate" always seems too limited, especially if I have the formula bar enlarged.